# How to import geohash scala package in databricks?

Tags: scala, databricks, azure-databricks, geohashing

I am trying to use Geohash library for scala from this resource:  https://github.com/mumoshu/geohash-scala

It shows commands in getting started but since I am new to both databricks and scala, i can't figure out how to implement it. What is the best way to import geohash in databricks (Scala)

Desired output: I want to create a new column to my table as "geohash" using latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you can use "geohash" library using installed python libraries called "python-geohash".

Geohash is a Python module that provides functions for decoding and encoding Geohashes to and from latitude and longitude coordinates.

For more details, refer "[Python installed libraries](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/5.3.html#installed-python-libraries)" and "[Geohash](https://github.com/vinsci/geohash)".

Hope this helps.